# Git bash how to upload a project to a bit bucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

[image]

I'm now ready to use git with the git init command.

This is the problem after that.

I'm not sure about the git add command.

What exactly should I add to add a file?

Do I have to upload my modified file?

Not only that, but I do not know how to upload a project to a bit bucket.

If you have a link that has been described in detail,

will not you give me that link?

There is not much data to refer to in Korea.

If you have any information, please share it.

Comment: Too many questions. I feel you should start here https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial before SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [BitBucket official doc](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.htmll):

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin ORIGIN_URL 
git push -u origin master
```

Where `ORIGIN_URL` is your repository url (e.g. `https://username@your.bitbucket.domain:7999 /yourproject/repo.git`)

Answer (score 0):

If GIT is not initialized

```
git init
```

In the question the git is already initialized

Try to find out the status with

```
git status
```

and if you find any files which has to be added for committing use

```
git add .
```

commit with

```
git commit -m "comment"
```

Add repository path

```
git remote add origin URL
```

URL - Project repository url

and push with

```
git push
```

Comment: I think a little more information is required because the enquirer sounds like a real newbie: I'd say go to https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket has instructions on how to do this:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-a-repository-877174034.html