# How to upload xcode project into bitbucket from scratch?

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

I am not able to upload project from Xcode to bitbucket. I have committed but it is not updating.

Comment: make sure you `push` your changes https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-push

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git bash how to upload a project to a bit bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005119/git-bash-how-to-upload-a-project-to-a-bit-bucket)

Answer (score 0):

When you `commit` your changes in `git` they are only tracked on your local machine.  This means that your local copy is versioned (and you could revert back to a previous version if needed)

If you want others to see your changes, you need to `push` those changes.

i.e. `git push`

This sends your commits to a common 'server' where others can retrieve them by performing a `pull`.

A really good set of tutorials for Git was put together by the folks at Atlassian: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/

In short, update your local copy before pushing your changes

```
git pull
```

Then push your changes:

```
git push
```

Comment: after pushing the project , error is coming as your local repository is out of date

Comment: @AngadSingh as always, when you are collaborating with others, you need to first do a `git pull`  - this will get your local repo up to date with the server - then you can do a `git push`

Comment: it is not working. can u please write the steps from scratch on how to upload project from Xcode?  Thanks

Comment: @AngadSingh describe 'not working' - there are a multitude of things that could go wrong.  Did you follow the tutorial? - the steps are in my updated answer